# Generate cURL request from WebAPI HTTP Request c#

Tags: c#, http, curl, asp.net-web-api

Trying to generate a cURL string from an incoming request in my c# web api. Not sure how to proceed. I could of course take all parts and create it myself but I was wondering if there are some easier ways of doing it?

For example a request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:54521/v2/Token'
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=usr' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

Then generating it again on my API - as a string, that I could use with cURL. Suggestions?

Comment: Easier ways of doing what? You already posted a curl FORM POST request that calls a Web API at `http://localhost:54521/v2/Token`. It doesn't matter if the HTTP endpoint is built using Web API or Node.js, this is just a FORM POST

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Serializing or reading the request as a string on my webapi.

Comment: Basically looking for a HTTP logging lib for webapi.

Comment: That's a *completely* different question. Request logging is already available whether you mean ASP.NET Framework or ASP.NET Core. In ASP.NET Framework, it's provided by IIS

Comment: I don't want the HTTP request to be outputted to the console or stored in a log file, I want to capture it in a middleware and send it to another service, so IIS logging would not help in this case(?)